# Vuex and reactivity in list rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

So I have a simple store:

```
const state = {
    cart: []
};
```

Here is how the cart should look like when it has items:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'My first product',
        price: 3,
        quantity: 3
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'My second product',
        price: 2,
        quantity: 7
    }
]
```

Here is my mutation for this object:

```
ADDPRODUCTTOCART (state,product,quantity) {
    for(var i = 0; i < state.cart.length; i++) {
        if(state.cart[i].id === product.id) {
            state.cart[i].quantity += quantity;
            return ;
        }
    }
    product.quantity = quantity;
    state.cart.push(product);
}
```

As you see, when adding a `product` to the `cart`, I first check if the same product is already in the cart. If it is, we change the `quantity` value. If it is not, I set the quantity property of the product object, and then I push it to the cart.

For your information, here is how the action to trigger this mutation is written:

```
export const addProductToCart = ({dispatch}, product, quantity) => {
    dispatch('ADDPRODUCTTOCART', product, quantity);
};
```

Then, I have a component:

```
export default {
    computed: {
        total() {
            var total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
                total += this.cart[i].price * this.cart[i].quantity;
            }
            return total;
        }
    },
    vuex: {
        getters: {
            cart: function (state) {
                return state.cart;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `total` computed property works well, it updates itself when I change the quantity of a `product` object in the `cart`.

**But if I try to display this `quantity` property in a `v-for` list, it does not update when `quantity` changes:**

```
<li v-for="product in cart" track-by="id">
    productID: {{ product.id }},
    quantity: {{ product.quantity }}
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgnvno7h/2/

Comment: I have created a fiddle with your code and it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/Lgnvno7h/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I edited your fiddle for my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgnvno7h/2/ it doesn't work anymore when I try to send an object contained in Vue data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass data from the `data` of component, you should remove the observers:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.products[0]))
```

Comment: be careful, `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` can make shit with dates inside `this.products`